# MapStruct is unable to use Lombok's builder with custom setterPrefix

Tags: lombok, mapstruct

I started integrating `MapStruct` with an existing `Spring Boot` application (that uses `Lombok`).

The problem is that most classes are following the builder pattern (implemented with `Lombok`), but they have a custom `setterPrefix`. I can see that `MapStruct` tells me that fields `withXXX` are not mapped, but I would like to know if there is a solution for this.

This is the setup:

```
plugins {
  id("io.freefair.lombok") // Notice how I'm using Lombok, so shifting dependencies is not an option
}

dependencies {
  annotationProcessor("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final")
  annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0")

  implementation("org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final")

  ...
}

java {
  consistentResolution {
    useCompileClasspathVersions()
  }
  sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
  targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

lombok {
  config["lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation"] = "true"
  config["lombok.log.fieldIsStatic"] = "false"
  config["lombok.log.fieldName"] = "logger"
  version = "1.18.18"
}
```

```java
@Setter
@Builder(setterPrefix = "with")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC, force = true)
public final class Model {
  @Getter(onMethod = @__(@ColumnName("model_id")))
  private Long id;

  ...
}
```

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR)
interface ModelMapper {
  Model valueFrom(CreateModelCommand command);
}
```

The only solutions I've found so far is:

- To declare a `@Mapping` for every field; e.g.: `@Mapping(source = "fieldName", target = "withFieldName")` ― quite the challenge!
- To just remove the custom `setterPrefix` from Lombok's `@Builder` annotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have non standard property names then the best approach is to use a [Custom Accessor Naming Strategy](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_custom_accessor_naming_strategy).

With it you can define how to extract the property name from a method.